# convert utf16le text file to utf-8 text file using vb script

Tags: vba

I am new to this scripting. I have a VBA script which the text data from `utf-16le` to `utf-8`, but the script is not performing what I expected. can anyone help to solve this. The file is loading but the file is not converting to `utf-8` format.
I need the destination file to be in `utf-8`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
'  <reference object="ADODB.Stream" />
'  <object id="stmUnicode" progId="ADODB.Stream" />
'  <object id="stmUTF8" progId="ADODB.Stream" />
'  <object id="stmNoBOM" progid="ADODB.Stream" />
'  <script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Dim stmUnicode
With stmUnicode
    .Open
    .Type = adTypeText
    .LineSeparator = adCRLF
    .Charset = "Unicode"
    .LoadFromFile "trial3.txt"
    With stmUTF8
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .LineSeparator = adLF
        .CharSet = "UTF-8"
        'Use Line operations to obtain LineSeparator action.
        Do Until stmUnicode.EOS
            .WriteText stmUnicode.ReadText(adReadLine), adWriteLine
        Loop
        stmUnicode.Close
        'Skip over UTF-8 BOM.
        .Position = 0 'Enable Type change.
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Position = 3 'UTF-8 BOM is in positions 0 through 2.
        With stmNoBOM
            .Open
            .Type = adTypeBinary
            stmUTF8.CopyTo stmNoBOM
            stmUTF8.Close
            .SaveToFile "trial4.txt", adSaveCreateOverWrite
            .Close
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Comment: VBScript or VBA? These are not the same. Please clarify in your tags!

Comment: It is the VBscript which I need.Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] and adjust your tags and text accordingly. If your tags are wrong, then the the question does not show up in the correct category and you probably don't get  the desired answers.